# $config must be a string or an array

Tags: arrays, laravel, string

I am having errors when trying to access the subscription section on my app. It's something with the stripe API, this error occurs mostly when server caches are being cleared. I checked to clear caches, check `config.app.php`, payment controller, and all of that but not really understanding the source of this error!

Therefore I need someone's help, maybe someone who had this issue before. Here is the code line for that on `vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/BaseStripeClient.php`. Please suggest a solution for this error! I will be grateful:

```
if (\is_string($config)) {

        $config = ['api_key' => $config];

    } elseif (!\is_array($config)) {

        throw new \Stripe\Exception\InvalidArgumentException('$config must be a string or an array');

    }
```

Comment: In the absence of any information about this error (like what `$config` is, or what the relevant piece of *your* code looks like) there's not much that can be determined.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you have STRIPE_SECRET and STRIPE_KEY in your .env file

then you can just go with `php artisan config:cache`

if you have these in you .env file and error persists try removing the the files in bootstrap/cache i.e. `rm -rf bootsrap/cache/*`

Answer (score 0):

Your application is pulling a cached version of its config. Delete the bootstrap/cache/config.php file and refresh your browser and the error should go away.

I haven't had much luck with running `php artisan cache:clear` so I just remove the file manually or run the command below.

If you run the terminal command `rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*` in the root of the application it should remove all the files in the cache directory.

Comment: Manually I have deleted the bootstrap/cache/config.php file and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**php artisan config:cache** run this command

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Your application is trying to access `STRIPE_KEY` from the .env file. But it fails to do so.
Make sure you have a key and if run the following command:
`php artisan config:clear`
personally for me `php artisan config:cache` did not do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

**Just run these commands**

```
php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear && composer clear-cache && composer dump-autoload && php artisan config:clear
```

**And then**

```
php artisan serve
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')`.

If you declared your .env variable using `env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')` in your Controller, there is a better approach.

First, run `php artisan config:cache`. This command is used to cache the configuration files, but if you're looking for your Stripe keys, they won't be available in the `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file. That's why running `config:cache` won't solve the issue.

To properly set your variables in the configuration, you need to define them in `services.php` like this:

```
    'stripe' => [
        'secret_key' => env('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY'),
        // You can also add subscription IDs or product IDs here
        'subscriptions' => [
            'premium' => env('STRIPE_PREMIUM_SUB_ID'),
        ]
    ],
```

After making these changes, run `php artisan config:cache` to cache the new keys.

You can then access these keys in your Controllers using the following syntax:

```
config('services.stripe.secret_key')
config('services.stripe.subscriptions.premium')
```

By following this approach, you can properly configure and access your Stripe keys.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the problem was `env()` function that I called outside of the config files.

In [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/configuration#configuration-caching) says that this can cause a problem with caching config files so the best way to go is to create those Stripe keys in `config/services.php` and get them there with `env()`